# launching wireguard with a keybining in I3

Tags: config, i3

i'm trying to use some keybinding to start my wireguard vpn, so I've used the following:

```
bindsym Ctrl+$alt+o exec --no-startup-id wg-quick down wg0 || wg-quick up wg0
```

but nothing seems to happen, I've also tried to set the suid bit to wg-quick, but still no luck.
after reading that `||`might cause some issue, i've also tried only the first part

```
bindsym Ctrl+$alt+o exec --no-startup-id wg-quick down wg0
```

with and without `--no-startup-id` but with no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This should be a solution:**

Create and add the line to the file: */etc/sudoers.d/wg-quick*

*yourusername* *yourhostname* = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wg-quick

(https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)

And then use the full path to wg0.conf in i3/config:

```
bindsym $mod+o exec "sudo wg-quick up /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf"
```

Comment: this is what I ended up doing, thx